# My Website Layout Is Broken But I Never Made Any Changes To It

Tags: html, css, layout

### The Problem

I have a webpage with multiple files, local images, and external style sheets. Today I started my Local Host like normal with Live Server and run the page on Google Chrome `108.0.5359.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)`. And the website layout was broken. Most notable is position, margin, and padding.

### Specific problems with the website:

- `Position: sticky` is working on all of the pages expect `index.html`  file
- Changing the `margin, padding, and position` values in the `styles.css` file does nothing but changing values like `color` does work
- The network tab says `200, ok` for `styles.css`

### Intended Results

This image shows a block of content that is working as intended:
[[image]This image shows a block of content that is working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYN5b.png)

And this image shows the content not loading properly:
[[image]And this image shows the content not loading properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQzhv.png)

Here's the website URL https://creative-daffodil-2c8447.netlify.app/ As well as a Github repository: https://github.com/tech-world-code/website-test

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't see how we can help you given such little information. What is it that isn't working on the site? Try to extract a small set of code which demonstrates the problem and put it into your question with a full explanation of what happens and what you wanted to happen. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: Use the developer console to see which file isn't loading correctly. And at a quick glance, you have spaces in some of your file names, which isn't best practice for websites.

Comment: @A more details have been added. Hope this helps!